# iOS Push Notification received but no message appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, push

I have set up a iOS app with push notifications enabled.

I can push messages to the app, for example the badge count works and updates accordingly.

But I never see the standard push notification popup in the lockscreen or elsewhere, the phones vibrates though, so the message gets through.

Even when the app is closed or not in background.

This is the payload:

```
        array(
            'alert' => array(
                'title' => "test",
                'body' => "some body..",
             ),
             "badge" => 5,
            'sound' => 'default'
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this payload.It works fine

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Hello from APNs Tester.","badge":"1"}}
```

You can test using app "APN Tester"

https://apn-tester-free.en.softonic.com/mac

Comment: happy to help (y)